# In eclipse AVD,I get "Unfortunately,Test1 has stopped working"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator

I did look at all the suggestions which I could get my hand on but those corrections were already there in my code..please have a look at this.
Basically I am trying to call another activity from the main activity after the click of an button.

```
//Here's the code of my main activity named Test1Activity:
public class Test1Activity extends Activity {

private int clicked=0;
public static final String pass="com.sanjay.test1._clicked";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.setId(1);
button2.setId(2);

button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      int id = v.getId();
      clicked=id;

    }
});
button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      int id = v.getId();
      clicked=id;
    }
});Intent i = new Intent(this,Sanjay.class);i.putExtra(pass,clicked);startActivity(i);
}
```

}

```
//Now my other Activity code : 
public class Sanjay extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int a;
TextView text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    a=getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Test1Activity.pass);

    text.setText(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}


//And my xml file of the second activity layout resource.
//I am not adding the main.xml as the program runs fine if I pass the startactivity(i) and the intent lines as comments.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `setText` with an int, as in this case it expects the `int` to be an ID of a resource.

Instead, make it a string:

```
text.setText("" + a);
```

Comment: Btw, is there something wrong with the logic? Cause its not working.Earlier it was showing 0 as output on AVD. Then I removed the initialisation of clicked. And now even after clicking the button,the AVD directly takes me to the second activity and still shows the result as 0. @Binyamin Sharet

Comment: You put the code to start new activity in the onCreate method, not in the listeners, so at the end of onCreate it will launch the new activity, before you press any button.

Comment: Can you show it how? If that's too much,just give an example or an link would also suffice.@Binyamin Sharet

Answer (score 1):

There was some errors in your code.

1) You were registering the onclicklisteners to button1 only. (two times)

2) You put your intent outside the OnClickListener() of the button. You should put it inside the OnClickListener();

Try This Way:

```
public class Test1Activity extends Activity {
private int clicked=0;
public static final String pass="com.sanjay.test1._clicked";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setId(1);
button2.setId(2);
button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  int id = v.getId();
  clicked=id;      
Intent i = new Intent(this,Sanjay.class);
i.putExtra(pass,clicked);
startActivity(i);      
}
});

button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  int id = v.getId();
  clicked=id;
Intent i = new Intent(this,Sanjay.class);
i.putExtra(pass,clicked);
startActivity(i);      
}
});
}
```

Comment: That's what I dont want. Creating many objects slows down the app.I am considering 16buttons and creating 16objects would definitely slow it down and hence I used the variable clicked so that I could avoid creating objects. And the code which you gave above gives Intent Constructor undefined error. @Aki143S

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one if you want to implement the OnClickListener in your activity.

Try This One:

```
public class Test1Activity extends Activity implements View.OnCLickListener(){
private int clicked=0;
public static final String pass="com.sanjay.test1._clicked";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);    
}

@Override
OnClick(View v)
{
  switch(v.getId())
  {
  case R.id.button1:
   //clicked = v.getId();
   //   OR
   //clicked = 1
   Intent i = new Intent(Test1Activity.this,Sanjay.class);
   i.putExtra(pass,clicked);
   startActivity(i);      
   break;

  case R.id.button2:
   //clicked = v.getId();
   //   OR
   //clicked = 2
   Intent i = new Intent(Test1Activity.this,Sanjay.class);
   i.putExtra(pass,clicked);
   startActivity(i);        
  }
}
}
```